# CMake and Clang Tooling linking error (out-of-tree)

Tags: c++, cmake, clang, llvm

I am trying to compile the [RecursiveASTVisitor example of Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/RAVFrontendAction.html) using a CMake file.
Building the project goes well, however, linking C++ executable fails with multiple undefined references to LLVM and Clang libraries.
I am building the example outside of the LLVM/Clang source file tree.

Here is my CMakeLists.txt (I am using [FindClang.cmake and FindLLVM.cmake from this project](https://github.com/woboq/woboq_codebrowser/tree/master/cmake/modules)):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
project(ifcount)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/modules
  ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})

message(STATUS "CMAKE module path: ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}")

find_path(LibClang_INCLUDE_DIR clang-c/Index.h)
find_library(LIBCLANG_LIBRARY NAMES clang)

find_package(LLVM REQUIRED)
find_package(LLVM REQUIRED CONFIG)
Find_Package(LLVM REQUIRED)
include_directories(${LLVM_INCLUDE_DIR})
link_directories(${LLVM_LIB_DIR})

message(STATUS "Found LLVM ${LLVM_PACKAGE_VERSION}")
message(STATUS "Using LLVMConfig.cmake in: ${LLVM_DIR}")

find_package(Clang REQUIRED)
find_package(Clang REQUIRED clangTooling libClang)
include_directories(${CLANG_INCLUDE_DIRS})

###
add_definitions(${LLVM_DEFINITIONS})
add_definitions(${Clang_DEFINITIONS})

add_definitions("-std=c++11")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${LLVM_COMPILE_FLAGS} -Wall -fno-rtti -g -std=c++11 -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(ifcount ${SOURCE_FILES})

llvm_map_components_to_libnames(llvm_libs support core irreader)

target_link_libraries(ifcount ${llvm_libs} ${LLVM_LDFLAGS} ${CLANG_LIBS})
```

And here is the output:

```
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 3.6.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 3.6.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/local/bin/clang
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/local/bin/clang -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/local/bin/clang++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/local/bin/clang++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- CMAKE module path: /home/adel/workspace/ifcount/cmake/modules
-- LLVM CXX flags: -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wall -W -Wno-unused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -Wno-comment -std=c++11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections   -D_GNU_SOURCE -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS
-- LLVM LD flags: -L/usr/local/lib-lrt -ldl -ltinfo -lpthread -lz
-- LLVM core libs: -lLLVMLTO -lLLVMObjCARCOpts -lLLVMLinker -lLLVMipo -lLLVMVectorize -lLLVMBitWriter -lLLVMIRReader -lLLVMAsmParser -lLLVMXCoreDisassembler -lLLVMXCoreCodeGen -lLLVMXCoreDesc -lLLVMXCoreInfo -lLLVMXCoreAsmPrinter -lLLVMSystemZDisassembler -lLLVMSystemZCodeGen -lLLVMSystemZAsmParser -lLLVMSystemZDesc -lLLVMSystemZInfo -lLLVMSystemZAsmPrinter -lLLVMSparcDisassembler -lLLVMSparcCodeGen -lLLVMSparcAsmParser -lLLVMSparcDesc -lLLVMSparcInfo -lLLVMSparcAsmPrinter -lLLVMR600CodeGen -lLLVMR600Desc -lLLVMR600Info -lLLVMR600AsmPrinter -lLLVMPowerPCDisassembler -lLLVMPowerPCCodeGen -lLLVMPowerPCAsmParser -lLLVMPowerPCDesc -lLLVMPowerPCInfo -lLLVMPowerPCAsmPrinter -lLLVMNVPTXCodeGen -lLLVMNVPTXDesc -lLLVMNVPTXInfo -lLLVMNVPTXAsmPrinter -lLLVMMSP430CodeGen -lLLVMMSP430Desc -lLLVMMSP430Info -lLLVMMSP430AsmPrinter -lLLVMMipsDisassembler -lLLVMMipsCodeGen -lLLVMMipsAsmParser -lLLVMMipsDesc -lLLVMMipsInfo -lLLVMMipsAsmPrinter -lLLVMHexagonCodeGen -lLLVMHexagonAsmPrinter -lLLVMHexagonDesc -lLLVMHexagonInfo -lLLVMCppBackendCodeGen -lLLVMCppBackendInfo -lLLVMARMDisassembler -lLLVMARMCodeGen -lLLVMARMAsmParser -lLLVMARMDesc -lLLVMARMInfo -lLLVMARMAsmPrinter -lLLVMAArch64Disassembler l-LLVMAArch64CodeGen -lLLVMAArch64AsmParser -lLLVMAArch64Desc -lLLVMAArch64Info -lLLVMAArch64AsmPrinter -lLLVMAArch64Utils -lLLVMTableGen -lLLVMDebugInfo -lLLVMOption -lLLVMX86Disassembler -lLLVMX86AsmParser -lLLVMX86CodeGen -lLLVMSelectionDAG -lLLVMAsmPrinter -lLLVMX86Desc -lLLVMMCDisassembler -lLLVMX86Info -lLLVMX86AsmPrinter -lLLVMX86Utils -lLLVMJIT -lLLVMLineEditor -lLLVMMCAnalysis -lLLVMInstrumentation -lLLVMInterpreter -lLLVMCodeGen -lLLVMScalarOpts -lLLVMInstCombine -lLLVMTransformUtils -lLLVMipa -lLLVMAnalysis -lLLVMProfileData -lLLVMMCJIT -lLLVMTarget -lLLVMRuntimeDyld -lLLVMObject -lLLVMMCParser -lLLVMBitReader -lLLVMExecutionEngine -lLLVMMC -lLLVMCore -lLLVMSupport
-- LLVM JIT libs: -lLLVMX86Disassembler -lLLVMX86AsmParser -lLLVMX86CodeGen -lLLVMSelectionDAG -lLLVMAsmPrinter -lLLVMX86Desc -lLLVMObject -lLLVMMCParser -lLLVMBitReader -lLLVMMCDisassembler -lLLVMX86Info -lLLVMX86AsmPrinter -lLLVMX86Utils -lLLVMJIT -lLLVMExecutionEngine -lLLVMCodeGen -lLLVMScalarOpts -lLLVMInstCombine -lLLVMTransformUtils -lLLVMipa -lLLVMAnalysis -lLLVMTarget -lLLVMMC -lLLVMCore -lLLVMSupport
-- LLVM JIT objs: 
-- Found LLVM: /usr/local/include
-- Found LLVM 3.6.0svn
-- Using LLVMConfig.cmake in: /usr/local/share/llvm/cmake
-- Clang libs: /usr/local/lib/libclangFrontend.a/usr/local/lib/libclangDriver.a/usr/local/lib/libclangCodeGen.a/usr/local/lib/libclangSema.a/usr/local/lib/libclangAnalysis.a/usr/local/lib/libclangRewrite.a/usr/local/lib/libclangAST.a/usr/local/lib/libclangParse.a/usr/local/lib/libclangLex.a/usr/local/lib/libclangBasic.a/usr/local/lib/libclangARCMigrate.a/usr/local/lib/libclangEdit.a/usr/local/lib/libclangFrontendTool.a/usr/local/lib/libclangRewrite.a/usr/local/lib/libclangSerialization.a/usr/local/lib/libclangTooling.a/usr/local/lib/libclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers.a/usr/local/lib/libclangStaticAnalyzerCore.a/usr/local/lib/libclangStaticAnalyzerFrontend.a/usr/local/lib/libclangSema.a
-- Found Clang: /usr/local/include
-- Clang libs: /usr/local/lib/libclangFrontend.a/usr/local/lib/libclangDriver.a/usr/local/lib/libclangCodeGen.a/usr/local/lib/libclangSema.a/usr/local/lib/libclangAnalysis.a/usr/local/lib/libclangRewrite.a/usr/local/lib/libclangAST.a/usr/local/lib/libclangParse.a/usr/local/lib/libclangLex.a/usr/local/lib/libclangBasic.a/usr/local/lib/libclangARCMigrate.a/usr/local/lib/libclangEdit.a/usr/local/lib/libclangFrontendTool.a/usr/local/lib/libclangRewrite.a/usr/local/lib/libclangSerialization.a/usr/local/lib/libclangTooling.a/usr/local/lib/libclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers.a/usr/local/lib/libclangStaticAnalyzerCore.a/usr/local/lib/libclangStaticAnalyzerFrontend.a/usr/local/lib/libclangSema.a/usr/local/lib/libclangFrontend.a/usr/local/lib/libclangDriver.a/usr/local/lib/libclangCodeGen.a/usr/local/lib/libclangSema.a/usr/local/lib/libclangAnalysis.a/usr/local/lib/libclangRewrite.a/usr/local/lib/libclangAST.a/usr/local/lib/libclangParse.a/usr/local/lib/libclangLex.a/usr/local/lib/libclangBasic.a/usr/local/lib/libclangARCMigrate.a/usr/local/lib/libclangEdit.a/usr/local/lib/libclangFrontendTool.a/usr/local/lib/libclangRewrite.a/usr/local/lib/libclangSerialization.a/usr/local/lib/libclangTooling.a/usr/local/lib/libclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers.a/usr/local/lib/libclangStaticAnalyzerCore.a/usr/local/lib/libclangStaticAnalyzerFrontend.a/usr/local/lib/libclangSema.a
-- Found Clang: /usr/local/include;/usr/local/include
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/adel/workspace/ifcount/build
Scanning dependencies of target ifcount
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ifcount.dir/main.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ifcount
```

And finally, the errors are too numerous, here are some of their input:

```
/usr/local/bin/../lib/libclangFrontend.a(CompilerInvocation.cpp.o): In function `llvm::opt::arg_iterator::arg_iterator(llvm::opt::Arg* const*, llvm::opt::ArgList const&, llvm::opt::OptSpecifier, llvm::opt::OptSpecifier, llvm::opt::OptSpecifier)':
CompilerInvocation.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm3opt12arg_iteratorC2EPKPNS0_3ArgERKNS0_7ArgListENS0_12OptSpecifierES9_S9_[_ZN4llvm3opt12arg_iteratorC5EPKPNS0_3ArgERKNS0_7ArgListENS0_12OptSpecifierES9_S9_]+0x5c): undefined reference to `llvm::opt::arg_iterator::SkipToNextArg()'
/usr/local/bin/../lib/libclangFrontend.a(CompilerInvocation.cpp.o): In function `llvm::opt::arg_iterator::operator++()':
CompilerInvocation.cpp:(.text._ZN4llvm3opt12arg_iteratorppEv[_ZN4llvm3opt12arg_iteratorppEv]+0x26): undefined reference to `llvm::opt::arg_iterator::SkipToNextArg()'
/usr/local/bin/../lib/libclangFrontend.a(CompilerInvocation.cpp.o): In function `llvm::opt::ArgList::hasArg(llvm::opt::OptSpecifier) const':
CompilerInvocation.cpp:(.text._ZNK4llvm3opt7ArgList6hasArgENS0_12OptSpecifierE[_ZNK4llvm3opt7ArgList6hasArgENS0_12OptSpecifierE]+0x1c): undefined reference to `llvm::opt::ArgList::getLastArg(llvm::opt::OptSpecifier) const'
/usr/local/bin/../lib/libclangFrontend.a(CompilerInvocation.cpp.o): In function `getOptimizationLevel(llvm::opt::ArgList&, clang::InputKind, clang::DiagnosticsEngine&)':
CompilerInvocation.cpp:(.text._ZL20getOptimizationLevelRN4llvm3opt7ArgListEN5clang9InputKindERNS3_17DiagnosticsEngineE+0x8d): undefined reference to `llvm::opt::ArgList::getLastArg(llvm::opt::OptSpecifier) const'
CompilerInvocation.cpp:(.text._ZL20getOptimizationLevelRN4llvm3opt7ArgListEN5clang9InputKindERNS3_17DiagnosticsEngineE+0xc6): undefined reference to `llvm::opt::Option::matches(llvm::opt::OptSpecifier) const'
CompilerInvocation.cpp:(.text._ZL20getOptimizationLevelRN4llvm3opt7ArgListEN5clang9InputKindERNS3_17DiagnosticsEngineE+0xfe): undefined reference to `llvm::opt::Option::matches(llvm::opt::OptSpecifier) const'
CompilerInvocation.cpp:(.text._ZL20getOptimizationLevelRN4llvm3opt7ArgListEN5clang9InputKindERNS3_17DiagnosticsEngineE+0x136): undefined reference to `llvm::opt::Option::matches(llvm::opt::OptSpecifier) const'
/usr/local/bin/../lib/libclangFrontend.a(CompilerInvocation.cpp.o): In function `getOptimizationLevelSize(llvm::opt::ArgList&)':
CompilerInvocation.cpp:(.text._ZL24getOptimizationLevelSizeRN4llvm3opt7ArgListE+0x2a): undefined reference to `llvm::opt::ArgList::getLastArg(llvm::opt::OptSpecifier) const'
CompilerInvocation.cpp:(.text._ZL24getOptimizationLevelSizeRN4llvm3opt7ArgListE+0x5f): undefined reference to `llvm::opt::Option::matches(llvm::opt::OptSpecifier) const'
/usr/local/bin/../lib/libclangFrontend.a(CompilerInvocation.cpp.o): In function `addDiagnosticArgs(llvm::opt::ArgList&, llvm::opt::OptSpecifier, llvm::opt::OptSpecifier, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >&)':
CompilerInvocation.cpp:(.text._ZL17addDiagnosticArgsRN4llvm3opt7ArgListENS0_12OptSpecifierES3_RSt6vectorISsSaISsEE+0x188): undefined reference to `llvm::opt::Option::matches(llvm::opt::OptSpecifier) const'
/usr/local/bin/../lib/libclangFrontend.a(CompilerInvocation.cpp.o): In function `ParseAnalyzerArgs(clang::AnalyzerOptions&, llvm::opt::ArgList&, clang::DiagnosticsEngine&)':
CompilerInvocation.cpp:(.text._ZL17ParseAnalyzerArgsRN5clang15AnalyzerOptionsERN4llvm3opt7ArgListERNS_17DiagnosticsEngineE+0x5e): undefined reference to `llvm::opt::ArgList::getLastArg(llvm::opt::OptSpecifier) const'
CompilerInvocation.cpp:(.text._ZL17ParseAnalyzerArgsRN5clang15AnalyzerOptionsERN4llvm3opt7ArgListERNS_17DiagnosticsEngineE+0x132): undefined reference to `llvm::opt::Arg::getAsString(llvm::opt::ArgList const&) const'
CompilerInvocation.cpp:(.text._ZL17ParseAnalyzerArgsRN5clang15AnalyzerOptionsERN4llvm3opt7ArgListERNS_17DiagnosticsEngineE+0x204): undefined reference to `llvm::opt::ArgList::getLastArg(llvm::opt::OptSpecifier) const'
CompilerInvocation.cpp:(.text._ZL17ParseAnalyzerArgsRN5clang15AnalyzerOptionsERN4llvm3opt7ArgListERNS_17DiagnosticsEngineE+0x2d8): undefined reference to `llvm::opt::Arg::getAsString(llvm::opt::ArgList const&) const'
CompilerInvocation.cpp:(.text._ZL17ParseAnalyzerArgsRN5clang15AnalyzerOptionsERN4llvm3opt7ArgListERNS_17DiagnosticsEngineE+0x3aa): undefined reference to `llvm::opt::ArgList::getLastArg(llvm::opt::OptSpecifier) const'
CompilerInvocation.cpp:(.text._ZL17ParseAnalyzerArgsRN5clang15AnalyzerOptionsERN4llvm3opt7ArgListERNS_17DiagnosticsEngineE+0x4fe): undefined reference to `llvm::opt::Arg::getAsString(llvm::opt::ArgList const&) const'
CompilerInvocation.cpp:(.text._ZL17ParseAnalyzerArgsRN5clang15AnalyzerOptionsERN4llvm3opt7ArgListERNS_17DiagnosticsEngineE+0x5d0): undefined reference to `llvm::opt::ArgList::getLastArg(llvm::opt::OptSpecifier) const'
CompilerInvocation.cpp:(.text._ZL17ParseAnalyzerArgsRN5clang15AnalyzerOptionsERN4llvm3opt7ArgListERNS_17DiagnosticsEngineE+0x6e4): undefined reference to `llvm::opt::Arg::getAsString(llvm::opt::ArgList const&) const'
CompilerInvocation.cpp:(.text._ZL17ParseAnalyzerArgsRN5clang15AnalyzerOptionsERN4llvm3opt7ArgListERNS_17DiagnosticsEngineE+0x7b6): undefined reference to `llvm::opt::ArgList::getLastArg(llvm::opt::OptSpecifier) const'
CompilerInvocation.cpp:(.text._ZL17ParseAnalyzerArgsRN5clang15AnalyzerOptionsERN4llvm3opt7ArgListERNS_17DiagnosticsEngineE+0x8aa): undefined reference to `llvm::opt::Arg::getAsString(llvm::opt::ArgList const&) const'
CompilerInvocation.cpp:(.text._ZL17ParseAnalyzerArgsRN5clang15AnalyzerOptionsERN4llvm3opt7ArgListERNS_17DiagnosticsEngineE+0xc3f): undefined reference to `llvm::opt::ArgList::getLastArgValue(llvm::opt::OptSpecifier, llvm::StringRef) const'
```

Any help or tips would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to link against the LLVMOptions library. See if "options" is a supported `llvm_map_components_to_libnames` target in your LLVM version, or just add it as a `target_link_library`.

Comment: Hi, option is supported, but adding it to `llvm_map_components_to_libnames`, or adding LLVMOption to `target_link_library` doesn't fix the linking problem. Still having the same error as above.

Comment: The order in which linker flags appear on the command line is important as there are dependencies between the libraries. Try putting `LLVMOption` at the start of your `target_link_libraries`.

Comment: This still didn't work. I tried changing order around, but still no solution.
However, I just found this [CMakeLists.txt with clang](https://include-what-you-use.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/CMakeLists.txt) that seems to work (after tweaking) on my example. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I ended up using rewriting CMakeLists.txt based on [this particular file](https://include-what-you-use.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/CMakeLists.txt).

Here is the modified working file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
project(ifcount)

set(LLVM_PATH /home/adel/Downloads/llvm)
link_directories(${LLVM_PATH}/lib)
include_directories(${LLVM_PATH}/include)

add_definitions(
-D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS
-D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS
)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fno-rtti -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(ifcount ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(ifcount
  clangFrontend
  clangSerialization
  clangDriver
  clangParse
  clangSema
  clangAnalysis
  clangAST
  clangBasic
  clangEdit
  clangLex
  clangTooling
)

target_link_libraries(ifcount
  LLVMX86AsmParser # MC, MCParser, Support, X86Desc, X86Info
  LLVMX86Desc # MC, Support, X86AsmPrinter, X86Info
  LLVMX86AsmPrinter # MC, Support, X86Utils
  LLVMX86Info # MC, Support, Target
  LLVMX86Utils # Core, Support
  LLVMipo
  LLVMScalarOpts
  LLVMInstCombine
  LLVMTransformUtils
  LLVMipa
  LLVMAnalysis
  LLVMTarget
  LLVMOption # Support
  LLVMMCParser # MC, Support
  LLVMMC # Object, Support
  LLVMObject # BitReader, Core, Support
  LLVMBitReader # Core, Support
  LLVMCore # Support
  LLVMSupport
)

include(FindCurses)
target_link_libraries(ifcount
    pthread
    z
    dl
    ${CURSES_LIBRARIES}
)
```

Comment: better use `llvm-config --src-root` for $LLVM_PATH

Comment: Thanks Hongxu, that's much helpful.

Comment: @HongxuChen Could you elaborate a bit more about your suggestion?

Comment: @isPrime `LLVM_PATH` can be set with `llvm-config --src-root` specified one, rather than hard coded.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to use `set(LLVM_PATH "`$(LLVM_BIN_PATH)/llvm-config --src_root`")
` But cmake cannot get the result as a string.

Comment: This helped me as well! `target_link_libraries(...exec...  LLVMBitstreamReader LLVMRemarks LLVMBinaryFormat LLVMCore LLVMSupport ...other stuff...)`