# Add LLVM to project using cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, llvm, llvm-c++-api, llvm-3.0

I'm trying to add LLVM to a cmake project, using cygwin as a compiler. I downloaded LLVM from cygwin's installer (just installed all of the llvm related packages). The files are there, however I cannot include LLVM in my project. I tried using the official guide for 3.5.2 (the version it installed) and my CMakeLists.txt looks like

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(Lang)

find_package(LLVM REQUIRED CONFIG)

message(STATUS "Found LLVM ${LLVM_PACKAGE_VERSION}")
message(STATUS "Using LLVMConfig.cmake in: ${LLVM_DIR}")


include_directories(${LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_definitions(${LLVM_DEFINITIONS})
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

add_executable(Lang ${SOURCE_FILES})

llvm_map_components_to_libnames(llvm_libs support core irreader)

# Link against LLVM libraries
target_link_libraries(Lang ${llvm_libs})
```

However, I get a bunch of errors like these

[image]

Am I doing something wrong? All I want to do is to use LLVM in my project.

Comment: You should figure out the libraries for the components you need. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/25783251/1938163

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cmake and clang tooling linking error (outside of source tree)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25782537/cmake-and-clang-tooling-linking-error-outside-of-source-tree)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As indicated by Marco A. in the comments, the problem were missing libraries. This link helped resolve the issue, and everything seems to be working normally now. https://stackoverflow.com/a/25783251/1938163

Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome :) Mark it as an answer and perhaps expand on the solution if you'd like.

Answer (score 20):

The answer here is stale.
In newer versions of LLVM, there is an included tool to include LLVM inside a CMake project.
Please see the documentation of [how to embed LLVM in your project](http://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html#embedding-llvm-in-your-project)

You'll thus have this in your project CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.3)
project(SimpleProject)

find_package(LLVM REQUIRED CONFIG)

message(STATUS "Found LLVM ${LLVM_PACKAGE_VERSION}")
message(STATUS "Using LLVMConfig.cmake in: ${LLVM_DIR}")

# Set your project compile flags.
# E.g. if using the C++ header files
# you will need to enable C++11 support
# for your compiler.

include_directories(${LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_definitions(${LLVM_DEFINITIONS})

# Now build our tools
add_executable(simple-tool tool.cpp)

# Find the libraries that correspond to the LLVM components
# that we wish to use
llvm_map_components_to_libnames(llvm_libs support core irreader)

# Link against LLVM libraries
target_link_libraries(simple-tool ${llvm_libs})
```

This should work.
If you are having problems on windows, install the source package and not the binary package as suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48947973/use-llvm-in-a-cmake-build)

if you have this error:

```
CommandLine Error: Option 'help-list' registered more than once!
LLVM ERROR: inconsistency in registered CommandLine options
```

replace the `${llvm_libs}` in `target_link_libraries()` by `LLVM`
you can see [this github thread](https://github.com/CastXML/CastXML/issues/102)

Comment: that is effectively the same code as in the question